# How can I become vegetarian/vegan when I have allergies to many fruits, vegetables, grains, nuts and spices?

Tags: vegetarian-diet, meat-substitutes, transitioning-diets

I eat too much meat and often think about reducing it, but I seriously don't know how to replace the meat and avoid being hungry all the time.

I read that veganism can help with allergies, but my problem is that I am allergic to a lot of vegetables and fruits, like apples, bananas, plums, celery, bell pepper, tomatoes, hazelnuts, walnuts, almonds, avocados, wheat, rye, and to spices like paprika and curry. Also, I am getting more allergies out of nowhere, so I must consume vegetables and fruits very carefully or my ears start to itch and larynx will swell, or I'm getting breathing problems.

I don't show allergic reactions to any kind of meat or dairy products.

How to become a vegetarian or vegan with all these allergies?

Comment: Are your allergies true, "IgE-mediated" allergies confirmed by your doctor? It sounds unusual to me to have true allergies to so many foods.

Comment: For the sake if the question, it's probably more helpful to assume that the OP has a legit condition, and focus on providing advice that you would for true allergies.

Comment: For the OP, it is crucial to know if he has true allergies or not and if he has some underlying disorder causing them. Some alternative healers often perform tests that show multiple IgG-mediated allergies, which are not true allergies. Many people actually have some IgG response to certain foods. On the other hand, there is a group of disorders called eosinophilic gastrointestinal disorders (EGID), which come with multiple allergies. Without knowing the medical facts we are on the way to give a potentially misleading personal medical advice.

Comment: Personal medical advice would be, "don't eat [foods]" or "eat small amounts of [for] to build up a tolerance." Such answers should be avoided, I agree. However, _for this Q&A_, assume that the OP cannot eat the listed foods, and suggest veg*n options that are not excluded. (Asking OP to confirm any recommendations with a professional is always encouraged, particularly when the restrictions seem more strictly limited than usual.) If you feel that I'm not approaching this well, or the question should be closed etc., please post on [meta]. I am not infallible and I welcome discussion :)

Comment: I wanted to comment on the question above, but unfortunately, I do't have enough reputation. Yes, my allergies are true allergies. I am also allergic to a lot of pollen, dust mites, dogs ad birds. Some of the above food allergies are cross-allergies. Is it possible to lead a vegetarian or vegan and diverse, healthy life with these problems or not?

Comment: That is weird. You should be able to leave a comment to your question no matter the reputation. Answering it with additional information is, unfortunately, not the way to do it though. Would you consider moving your additional information to your question as an Edit? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa: OP seems to use two accounts (with the same display name). I flagged it for a mod to merge the accounts.

Comment: @Markus Wehmeyer, you've said your allergies are true ones and you get new ones out of nowhere. My suggestion is that you discuss with an allergologist, who can make certain tests, which can show if there is any _pattern_ in your allergies that could help predict allergies you are not aware of yet. Also, knowing the pattern might lead a doctor to discover a certain potentially treatable condition with allergies to multiple foods, such as eosinophilic gastrointestinal disorders.  Next to ask: are your allergies permanent and is there any trigger causing this you could remove.

Comment: I'm not voting to close the question and, in this particular case, I don't see a problem if it asks for a personal advice. The problem would be an answer that would, even if unintentionally, give a misleading advice that could lead to an actual medical problem. I think it's highly unlikely to make a helpful list of vegan foods in the situation, where we do not know, which all allergies the OP has and if he has any underlying condition causing them.

Comment: @Jan, the trigger causing the allergies is that I eat food. I am allergic to a lot of plants, and new cross-allergies are coming in every now and then. I am not allergic to meat, eggs, fish, milk and the few fruits and vergetables that are left.

Comment: @badjohn I tried tofu and soy, don't like it much, but it's okay. I'm not reacting allergic to this day, but things can change. Do you think a vegetarian and healthy diet would be possible with the few things I can eat?

Comment: @MarkusWehmeyer, I was thinking about the possibility that there could be a trigger, maybe an underlying disorder or something what you came in contact with once (something other than food) that could trigger your allergies. I can't say more but an allergologist could. I was really thinking it could be a good idea to get all your medical facts together and then thinking from there.

Answer (score 5):

With such a long list of allergies, you should seek professional advice rather than hope to find it on the internet.

Certainly, this long list of allergies will mean that becoming vegetarian or vegan will be a significant challenge.

Vegetarian may be a sensible starting point or compromise.  You have not mentioned eggs and milk in your list of allergies.  Try different sorts of eggs and milk if necessary.  If you are not allergic to these then you may be able to avoid meat and be as healthy as you are now.

For vegan products, have you tried any soya products e.g. bean curd?  How about TVP?

Answer (score 3):

There are tests for allergies in a lot of countries, you should check with your personal doctor or if there is any clinic close to you that provide them, That should be your first step, even if you are not going to convert to vegan you should get check up to be able to adapt your diet to your allergies without been afraid to what or not you could eat. After that you could obtain tons of on-line resources or even books to help you out going around your allergies to a healthy diet. There are books from how to transition into a vegan diet and lifestyle to complete vegans cookbooks.

A couple of them are:

1. Vegan For Life, By Jack Norris, RD and Virginia Messina, MPH, RD
2. Frugal Vegan, By Katie Koteen and Kate Kasbee
3. Vegan in 7, Rita Serano
4. The Vegan Cheat Sheet, by Amy Cramer and Lisa McComesey